# Retry connection when it takes too long

Tags: angular, http, angular5, retrywhen

Is it possible in Angular to retry a connection when the calls stays for more then a couple of seconds on pending?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Should be doable with a combination of `pipe`, `timeout` and `retry` from Rxjs. If `timeout` is exceeded, `retry` 4 times, else, `catchError`.

```
return this.httpClient.post(url, data, httpOptions).pipe(
  timeout(3000),
  retry(4),
  catchError(<DO SOMETHING>)
);
```

Comment: what does the .pipe do and where can i put the .map with the response now?

Comment: @Hans - `.pipe()` combines the the operators into an observable stream. Using Angulars `HttpClient`, the methods already return an observable of the response, so you can do any manipulation in your observer. e.g

`this.httpClient.post(url, data, httpOptions).pipe(
        timeout(3000), 
        retry(4), 
        catchError(this.handleError)).subscribe((result: any) => { 
                   // do your data manipulation here.....
         });`

Comment: As an aside, you can encapsulate your http methods in a service (e.g `post`, `get`, etc), that way you can set defaults for timeouts and retries etc, then just subscribe to a service method (for example... `doPost<T>`) in your other components.

More here: https://angular.io/guide/http#getting-json-data